# Student requests my presence while doing evaluation without grades

Tags: ethics, teaching, tutoring

As a private tutor, a student has requested my presence during an evaluation that does not involve assigning grades. I'm unsure about the ethical implications of this. Could the community provide guidance on whether it's ethically appropriate for me to be present during such an evaluation, and if so, how should I approach it to maintain academic integrity and fairness?

The student has to complete and answer several points and submit it to online campus. I guess he wants clarifications on the requests because he is studying a functional programming language for the first time, but I am unsure because the task says that he can look up google, search on his books, but do not ask classmates.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If they cannot ask for help from classmates, I think that also rules out asking a private tutor. This is an evaluation of what the student is capable of, not what you are capable of.

Comment: *Being present* is not the same as *providing clarifications*. You need to be very explicit as to what the student expects you to do, and what the examining body is comfortable with. Probably easiest to have your student ask the institution, with you in cc, and asking the institution to reply-all, so you are all on the same page. I would expect that a request for you to be present and provide "clarifications" will be denied.

Comment: What's the purpose of an evaluation that does not involve assigning grades? I would assume it would involve the instructor needing to gauge where students are at to inform the pedagogy of the course. In that case, it would be extremely detrimental for a student who relies on a tutor to give an impression that they have more mastery of the subject than they actually do.

Comment: Does "that does not involve assigning grades" modify "my presence" or "an evaluation"? Is it possible he needs you to act as a proctor?

Comment: Thank you all of you ! I'll provide some clarifications. I think the purpose, as @Brian Krause guesses is the need to gauge where students are. Then, Iregarding proctoring, that's not the case. He wants me there, and now thank to your insights, I should ask him **why** he needs me there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they simply want you to observe and then to advise them later it would be fine. However, if they want your help in this exercise it would almost certainly cross ethical boundaries.

The issue isn't so much whether it is graded or not, but rather how the situation helps or hinders their learning. Helping them in that situation wouldn't help them learn.

You might also ask whether the student would object you you speaking with the instructor and getting advice from them about what you can and should do.

But, observing a student working on problems is a good way to help structure your tutoring. Especially if it gives you insight into any learning issues they might have that you are qualified to address.

---

Edited to add, from comments:

One thing that the student may need, actually, is self confidence. And that comes from solving problems on their own without suggestions. They also need to learn how to properly interpret questions/exercises as stated by the professor. In tutorial you can help with that, but not in a situation like this. Eventually they will be expected to do it for "credit" and this is an excellent time for them to practice so that they can be successful then.

If you tell them, as you should, that you can't "help" them in this, you might also want to explain why. It is to help them with their learning, not hurt them.

Comment: Thank you Buffy ! I told the student that I would like to observe him while doing the evaluation; that would be useful information for our lessons. But he said: "I don't want you to just observe; I want you to help me with the exercises as you do in the lessons". Also, he clarified that he get marks but as a diagnose. They do not count towards the subject. The professor just wants to know where his students are right now.

Comment: I advise skipping it. Strongly. If they can't handle it in this situation, how will they get through it when it really counts?

Comment: Thank you for the advice Buffy !

Comment: I just saw your edit. Great point, I think. If I am always solving things with him, he wouldn't know which steps he would have to take in order to improve. We would miss feedback reality gives us.

Comment: @F. Zer The most helpful thing would be to explain to the student why his attitude (trying to appear better than he actually is on a "diagnostic" test) is non-sensical and counter-productive. The best thing would be if he understands that the idea that he should at all times appear as if he understands things even if he doesn't is completely counter-productive when it comes to actually improving his knowledge. These students sometimes have the implicit belief that there is something wrong or shameful about not understanding things, which then prevents them from actually improving.

Comment: That is absolutely spot on, @Adam Přenosil. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer contains the only right answer: "helping" a student during a test is unethical. In fact, it's just cheating.

However, you should be aware of the market you are working in. In a world where online tests are getting common, providing such help has become an industry on itself. You just need to google "help online exams" to found plenty of services that "help" students during tests or simply take the tests for them.

Therefore, in the minds of some students, the line between helping them to learn and telling them the answers to the tests may be becoming a very blurred line.

In summary, please do the right thing - and I think you knew what the right thing was even before asking here - but be aware that you are competing with a lot of private tutors who disregard ethics. Being ethical has never been very easy, but online tests make it harder. I hope it will be fixed at some point when employers discover that some diplomas can't be taken at face value.

Comment: Thank you so much and +1 for such an amazing answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this: “some diplomas can't be taken at face value” ?

Comment: @F.Zer - When students graduate they get a diploma which is assumed to be a proof that they have learned something, and employers can rely on them to select employees. If cheating in online exams become widespread enough, some students will get diplomas without having learned anything and when employers realize, such diplomas will lose their value as a tool to get a job. Hopefully, universities will react and  make sure their assessment methods are reliable and secure.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is a great answer. Do you have any theory about why a student would like to get a diploma which certified he/she possesses skills that they don’t really have ? Why would someone want that? How are they going to deal with the actual job?

Comment: You are asking about why cheating exists. If all students wanted diplomas and grades which certify the knowledge they actually have, cheating wouldn't exist, but it exists. If you want to know about why cheating exists, you can post another question, and I'm sure there are people more qualified than me to answer.

Comment: Thank you Pere for you input. My specific concern is cheating in this case doesn’t give them any benefits at all. That’s what I think, unless I am missing something. Why anyone would get into the trouble of cheating to get no benefit at all? In the end, they wouls have to do the job with the skills the diploma certifies they had, aren’t they ?

Comment: As I said, if you want to ask why some students cheat in university, you can post another question. However, if you want to get somebody to say to you that it's OK end ethical for you to help your student cheating in a test because it doesn't provide any undue benefit to the student, I'm afraid you are unlikely to get it here.

Comment: I am so sorry Pere ! Perhaps I explained badly myself ! No, of course I don’t want someone to say that it’s ethical to do it. And I do think that your answer is excellent. Thinking again, yes there is a benefit. He/she passes the exam without doing effort. But, my specific concern is that I can’t see any benefit in the long run. In the end, when the student gets a job, he will have to prove (and use) the skills certified by the diploma. So, the student is in fact doing a bad thing to himself in the long run. I hope I could explain better and my apologies again.

Comment: And that’s why I see the student is actually buying himself/herself a problem in the long run. That’s certainly not a benefit (in the long run).